# $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(\int_{0}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}\,dx-\frac{3}{4})$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, analysis, definite-integrals

I saw this problem in a problem book. and I have no idea how to find the limit here.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(\int\limits_{0}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}\,dx-\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
I know that$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}\,dx =\frac{3}{4}$$

> proof $$  \int _{0} ^ {\frac{1}{2}}  \sqrt[n]{(1-x)^n}dx   + \int _{{\frac{1}{2}}} ^ 1  \sqrt[n]{x^n}dx= \frac{3}{2} \leq \int _0 ^ 1  \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}dx \leq  \int _{0} ^ {\frac{1}{2}}  \sqrt[n]{2(1-x)^n}dx   + \int _{{\frac{1}{2}}} ^ 1  \sqrt[n]{2x^n}dx= \sqrt[n]{2}\frac{3}{2}$$  since $\lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{2}=1 $ thenby squeeze theorem $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{0}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}\,dx =\frac{3}{4}$

by attempt was to use the fact that
$I<\sqrt[n]{2}\frac{3}{4}$

so
$$I-\frac{3}{4}<\frac{3}{4}(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)$$
$$n^2(I-\frac{3}{4})<n^2(\frac{3}{4}(\sqrt[n]{2}-1))$$
but $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2(\frac{3}{4}(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)) =\infty $$
and here I got stuck

Comment: This problem has been asked today.

Comment: where ? If you can ,help me with this problem

Comment: Numerically it looks to be $\pi^2/48$. No idea where that comes from.

Comment: how did you get that answer ? also The answer is correct

Comment: I calculated it for really some really large $n$ using Mathematica. This also gave the next term in the asymptotic expansion as $\zeta(3)/8$, so it seems there's some zeta function stuff going on.

Comment: With some fancy changes of variables, you can get the equivalent limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^2\int_0^1((1+u^n)^{1/n}-1)/(1+u)^3du$. That binomial term looks more tractable now.

Comment: this is impressive but how did you get that what substitution did you apply? and this would solve the problem

Comment: what's the name of the book?@Ahmed

Comment: @
Sine of the Time
 sharpening mathematical analysis skills https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-77139-3

Comment: @Ahmed barak Allahu fik

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define $I_n$ by

\begin{align*}
I_n
&:= \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt[n]{x^n + (1-x)^n} \, \mathrm{d}x - \frac{3}{4}.
\end{align*}

Using the symmetry,

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} (1 - x)\left(1 + \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n \right)^{1/n} \, \mathrm{d}x - \frac{3}{4} \\
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} (1 - x) \left[ \left(1 + \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^n \right)^{1/n} - 1 \right] \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

Now we substitute $x = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{n}$. Then

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= \frac{1}{n} \int_{0}^{n/2} \left(1 + \frac{2t}{n}\right) \underbrace{\left[ \left(1 + \left(\frac{1 - 2t/n}{1 + 2t/n}\right)^n \right)^{1/n} - 1 \right]}_{[\blacksquare]} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

To analyze the behavior of this limit, we note that $\frac{1-x}{1+x} \leq e^{-2x}$ and $(1 + x)^{\alpha} \leq 1 + \alpha x$ for all $x \geq 0$ and $\alpha \in [0, 1]$. From this, we get

$$ 0 \leq [\blacksquare] \leq \frac{1}{n} e^{-4t}. $$

This allows us to invoke the dominated convergence theorem, concluding that

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2 I_n \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac{2t}{n}\right) n [\blacksquare] \mathbf{1}_{\{t \leq n/2\}} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \log(1 + e^{-4t}) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{48}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Let's denote $\displaystyle I(n)=\int\limits_{0}^1 \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}\,dx$, then
$$I(n)\overset{x=\frac t2+\frac12}{=}\frac12\int_0^1(1+t)\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}dt\overset{x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}}{=}2\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt[n]{(1+x^n)}}{(1+x)^3}dx$$
-this is the convenient form obtained by @eyeballfrog
$$=2\int_0^1\frac{e^\frac{\ln(1+x^n)}n}{(1+x)^3}dx=2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)^3}\left(1+\frac1n\ln(1+x^n)+\frac1{2n^2}\ln^2(1+x^n)+...\right)\tag{1}$$
$$=\frac34+\frac2n\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^n)}{(1+x)^3}dx+o\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)$$
In turn,
$$I_2(n)=\frac2{n}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^n)}{(1+x)^3}dx\overset{t=x^n}{=}\frac2{n^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)\,t^{\frac1n-1}}{(1+t^{\frac1n})^3}dt$$
The integrand is dominated by $\displaystyle f(t)=\frac{\ln(1+t)}t$. Taking the limit under the integral sign
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2I_2(n)=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}tdt=\frac{\pi^2}{48}$$

---

*Addendum*

We can evaluate third asymptotic term ($\sim\frac1{n^3}$). We have to take the third term from (1):
$$J_1=\frac1{n^2}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+x^n)}{(1+x)^3}dx\overset{t=x^n}{=}\frac1{n^3}\int_0^1\frac{t^{\frac1n-1}\ln^2(1+t)}{(1+t^\frac1n)^3}dt$$
$$=\frac1{8n^3}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}tdt+o\big(\frac1{n^3}\big)=\frac{\zeta(3)}{32n^3}+o\big(\frac1{n^3}\big)\tag{2}$$
We also have to extract the part $\sim\frac1{n^3}$ from the second term in (1):
$$J_2=\frac2n\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x^n)}{(1+x)^3}dx\overset{IBP}{=}-\frac1n\frac{\ln(1+x^n)}{(1+x)^2}\,\bigg|_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^2(1+x^n)}dx$$
$$\overset{x=e^{-t}}{=}-\frac{\ln 2}{4n}+\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(e^{nt}+1)(1+e^{-t})^2}$$
$$\overset{x=nt}{=}-\frac{\ln 2}{4n}+\frac1n\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(1+e^{-\frac xn})^2}$$
Dropping exponentially small corrections, we are allowed to decompose $e^{-\frac xn}$ into the series.
$$J_2=-\frac{\ln 2}{4n}+\frac1n\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(2-\frac xn+\frac{x^2}{2n^2}-...)^2}$$
$$=-\frac{\ln 2}{4n}+\frac1{4n}\int_0^\infty\left(1+\frac xn-\frac{x^2}{2n^2}+\frac34\frac{x^2}{n^2}+O\big(\frac1{n^3}\big)\right)\frac{dx}{e^x+1}$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{48}\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{16n^3}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}dx+O\big(\frac1{n^4}\big)\tag{3}$$
Taking the term $\sim\frac1{n^3}$ from (2) , together with (3) we get third asymptotic term:
$$I_3=\frac{\zeta(3)}{32n^3}+\frac1{16n^3}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{e^x+1}dx=\frac{\zeta(3)}{8n^3}\tag{4}$$
It means that
$$\boxed{\,\,I(n)=\frac34+\frac{\pi^2}{48n^2}+\frac{\zeta(3)}{8n^3}+O\big(\frac1{n^4}\big)\,\,}$$
Given the symmetry of several first asymptotic terms, we may suppose that a concise form for full asymptotics exists.

Comment: Maybe related, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-019-00235-z.

Comment: @Svyatoslav what does $o\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)$ mean , I see it very often but I don't know what it is. is $o\big(\frac1{n^2}\big)$ is somekind of special function ?

Comment: @Ahmed $o(1/n^2)$ means the term that declines more rapidly than $\frac1{n^2}$. It can be, for example, $\frac{C}{n^3}$ at $n\to\infty$

Comment: Nice ! When I introfuce the newt term $a=0.150259630131738$. Cheers & (+1)

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer.*

$$I_n=-\frac{3}{4}+2\int_{0}^{\frac 12} \sqrt[n]{x^n+(1-x)^n}\,\,dx$$

*Computing* them (for $10 \leq n \leq 1000$ by step of $10$) and using a quick and dirty linear regression
$$n^3\,I_n=a + b\,n$$ gives (long decimal numbers being truncated), with $R^2=0.9999999998917$,

$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} & \text{Confidence
   Interval} \\
 a & 0.148594 & 2.54\times 10^{-4} & \{0.148090,0.149097\} \\
 b & 0.205619 & 4.36\times 10^{-7} & \{0.205618,0.205620\} \\
\end{array}$$

$b=\frac {\pi^2}{48}$ is "obvious" (thanks to Wolfram Alpha).

For this value of $b$, re-tuning $a$ gives, at the level of $95$%
$$0.149414\leq a \leq 0.149974$$

Using
$$a=0.14969420124943726324726381376809257943038859$$ gives
$$I_{2000}=\color{red}{5.14229}013\times 10^{-8}\qquad \text{instead of} \qquad  5.14229654\times 10^{-8}$$  Searching the $ISC$, nothing "simple" came out.

Now, considering
$$n^3\,I_n=a + \frac {\pi^2}{48}\,n- \frac {b}{n}$$
$R^2=0.9999999999995880$ starts to be impressive

$$\begin{array}{|llll}
\hline
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Std Error} &
   \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.150313 & 8.49 \times 10^{-6} & \{0.150296,0.150330\} \\
 b & 0.119254 & 6.64 \times 10^{-4} & \{0.117936,0.120572\} \\
\end{array}$$ gives
$$I_{2000}=\color{red}{5.14229}712\times 10^{-8}\qquad \text{instead of} \qquad  5.14229654\times 10^{-8}$$

No luck searching the $ISC$.